# Dispaly different kind of delivery messages in view page

Tags: database, shipping, product-view, zipcode

please visit [link](http://test.collagekingapp.com/ship12345.html)

you can see there is an option to check delivery is available or not by entering zip code.

[image]

we saved list of zip codes in database table and if zip code is available in table, it show

"Delivery is avilable" otherwise it show " Not available".

example: 560043 is avialable. 5600431 is not available

I want to update this feature with following requirements.

for some zip codes, i want to display message as

1) Delivery is available, COD is available

for some other zip codes, i want to display message as

2) Delivery is available, COD is not available

Also for some,

3) Delivery is not available.

is this possible by saving zip codes in DB or is we have to save zip codes in files to get

this result ?

**view.phtml**

```
<?php  echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('checkdelivery/checkdelivery.phtml')->toHtml();?>
```

**checkdelivery.phtml**

```
<div class="block-content" >    <div id="block_info">
<img src ="" height= '35' width= '70'> 
<?php $blockLabel = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/block_title'); ?>
<strong><span><?php echo $this->__($blockLabel) ?></span></strong>


<input type="text" placeholder="Enter your PIN Code" class="input-text" maxlength="120" id="zipcode" size="20" name="zipcode" onkeypress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { return false;}">


<button type="button" name="zip-check" title="Check" class="button1" id="zip-check" ><span><?php echo $this->__('CHECK'); ?></span></button>
<div id="delivery-message"></div>
<?php $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html'); ?>
<div id="delivery-html"><?php echo $defaultHtml ?></div>

</div>  
</div>


<script>
    document.getElementById('zipcode').onkeypress = function(e){
        if (!e) e = window.event;
        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (keyCode == '13'){
          // Do your ajax process which you are doing on zip-check click button same way.

              new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
                    method: "get",
                    parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
                    onSuccess: function(transport) {
                             var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                             $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                             
                             $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
                             $('delivery-html').update(json.html); 
                    }
            });

          return false;
        }
      }
</script>


<script>
    Event.observe('zip-check', 'click', function(event){
        new Ajax.Request("<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkdelivery/index/index') ?>", {
            method: "get",
            parameters: {zipcode : $('zipcode').value },
            onSuccess: function(transport) {
                 var json = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                 $('delivery-message').update(json.message);                 
                 $('delivery-message').setStyle({ color: json.color});
                 $('delivery-html').update(json.html);  
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**controllers/indexcontroller.php**

```
public function indexAction() {

        $zip = $this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode');
        $pincodearray = array();
        $pindata = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/pincode');
        $pincodearray = explode(",", $pindata);
        $success = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/success_messgae');
        $failure = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/failure_messgae');
        $empty = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/empty_messgae');
        $successHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/success_html');
        $failureHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/failure_html');
        $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html');

        $trimedZip = trim($zip);
        $response = array();
        if(isset($trimedZip) && !empty($trimedZip)){
            if (in_array($trimedZip, $pincodearray)) {
                $response['message'] = $success;
                $response['color'] = 'green';
                $response['html'] = $successHtml;

            }else{
                $response['message'] = $failure;
                $response['color'] = 'red';
                $response['html'] = $failureHtml;

            }
        }else{
            $response['message'] = $empty;
            $response['color'] = 'orange';
            $response['html'] = $defaultHtml;
        }
        echo json_encode($response);exit;
    }
```

Comment: paste this `checkdelivery/index/index` code too

Comment: just return message based on zipcode

Comment: @QaisarSatti please check updated question.

Comment: @MineshPatel we stored zip codes in database, can you explain with code.

Comment: what is difference between normal zip code and some zipcode you want to show the different message?

Comment: @QaisarSatti only these 3 types are there : `1)Delivery is available, COD is available , 2)Delivery is available, COD is not available , 3)Delivery is not available.`

Comment: where are these message are stored??

Comment: @BabyinMagento added answer

Comment: @QaisarSatti please let me know if you want more clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **checkdelivery/index/index** action use below code

public function indexAction() {

```
    $zip = $this->getRequest()->getParam('zipcode');
    $pincodearray = array();
    $pindata = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/pincode');
    $pincodearray = explode(",", $pindata);
    $success = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/success_messgae');
    $failure = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/failure_messgae');
    $empty = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/empty_messgae');
    $successHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/success_html');
    $failureHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/failure_html');
    $defaultHtml = Mage::getStoreConfig('checkdelivery/general/default_html');

    //in below array add zipcode which have cod is available. I have add 12345,67890 for example purpose
    $pincodeCODarray = array(12345,67890,....);


    $trimedZip = trim($zip);
    $response = array();
    if(isset($trimedZip) && !empty($trimedZip)){
        if (in_array($trimedZip, $pincodearray)) {
            if (in_array($trimedZip, $pincodeCODarray)) {
              //Delivery is available, COD is available
                $response['message'] = $success;
                $response['color'] = 'green';
                $response['html'] = $successHtml;

            }else{
            //Delivery is available, COD is not available
                $response['message'] = "Delivery is available, COD is not available";
                $response['color'] = 'green';
                $response['html'] = $successHtml;

            }
        }else{
        //Delivery not available
            $response['message'] = "Delivery not available";
            $response['color'] = 'red';
            $response['html'] = $failureHtml;

        }
    }
    echo json_encode($response);exit;
}
```

Comment: i placed your code in `controllers/Indexcontroller.php` by replacing this line by this line.  `$model = Mage::getModel('your zipcode model');` by `$model = Mage::getModel('checkdelivery');` but it didt worked for me.

Comment: how to find our `zipcode model `?

Comment: This is model which you have created and store available code if you don't have any model regarding it. you can create an array for it. updated answer check it.

Comment: It is working in your site.I have just checked it.

Comment: i hide your code, so it was working. now i used our code, please check.

Comment: use only these zip codes : `'12345','67890'`

Comment: No man. you need to use your available code in this array. if(in_array($zipcode,$checkZipcode)){   this code check zipcode is in your available zipcode list or not

Comment: i will check your updated answer

Comment: i added your code like this : http://pastebin.com/7gM8VErm , please check once.

Comment: Your code is perfect why you need to change i have just give you an idea to do like that is quick approach to your requirement

Comment: sorry, i didt understood, are you telling no need to replace existed code, why its not working than ?

Comment: What is not working?I have checked your link is working

Comment: i want to display 3 kind of messages : `1) Delivery is available, COD is available 2) 2) Delivery is available, COD is not available 3) Delivery not available` . now only 3rd message is working. initial 2 messages i want.

Comment: now only `Delivery is available or not ` is working   i want to add COD also for this.

Comment: now after using your updated code   2nd and 3rd conditions are working, only 1st condition is not working : `Delivery is available, COD is available` i used `12345` zip code.

Comment: This is as per your need please check it carefully you have some issue in code must check if zip is available in available zip code and cod available zip code then it will display Delivery is available, COD is available

Answer (score 1):

Here is logic for your requirements

```
$codAvailabelZipCode = array('123456','678954'); // get it from another config or table

if(isset($trimedZip) && !empty($trimedZip)) {
    if (in_array($trimedZip, $pincodearray) && in_array($trimedZip,$codAvailabelZipCode)) {
        // 1) Delivery is available, COD is available

    }elseif (in_array($trimedZip, $pincodearray)) {
        //2) Delivery is available, COD is not available

    }else{
        // 3) Delivery is not available.

    }
}
```

Comment: than i have to store zip codes in another table?

Comment: You can store in another StoreConfig as well

Comment: but in 2 fields one with Delivery Available and one with COD Available

Comment: i' will try with different store now.

Comment: i found the store name : "French" , store id as "3" , than i stored some zip codes in this store.

now i am using 2 stores, "english" & "French"

now i have to display different messages for following 3 conditions.

`1)Zip codes present in both english & French 

2)Zip codes present in english & not in french

3)Zip codes not present in both english & french`

please give me the updated code for this

Comment: this is "French" store id  : http://prntscr.com/af1xj5

Comment: You need to filter zip code at store level now. You need to find out further.

Comment: Don't expect ready made code every time  from community.

Comment: I will check it